# Prove that the conditional expectation of functions of r.v.s allows factoring the function

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation

I'm trying to prove that, if $X, Y$ random variables and $r(x), s(x)$ functions then

$$\mathbb{E}(r(X)s(Y) | X) = r(X)\mathbb{E}(s(Y)|X)$$

What I do know is

$$\mathbb{E}(r(X)s(Y)|X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}r(x)s(y)\frac{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P_{Y}(y)}dx$$

However, I'm not even sure how to write the right-hand side because it seems like it should be a random variable, not a function of like the function above.  I would say

$$\mathbb{E}(s(Y)|X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s(y)\frac{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P_{Y}(y)}dx$$

but I don't understand what it could mean that this times $r(X)$ gets me the other side of the equation, which as I understand it, is a function of $y$ and not some random variable.  Even if it is a random variable I'm not sure how I could show they were equal since I can't imagine how you'd use the distribution technique or find a moment generating function.

Comment: "What I do know is..." - Can't be true, since the left-hand side is a random variable and the right-hand side is a number (oddly depending on some undefined $y$). How is conditional expectations defined to you?

Comment: @StefanHansen My definition is $E(X|Y=y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\frac{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P_{Y}(y)}dx$.  Is there one more natural for this context?

Comment: Usually, $E(X\mid Y)$ is defined to be the unique $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable that satisfies $E(E(X\mid Y);A)=E(X;A)$ for all $A\in\sigma(Y)$. With this definition, your claim is quite easy to show.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I may have figured this out.  The expressions on each side of the equation are not functions of $x$ or any such thing, but instead are random variables that are basically a transformation of $X$.  The conditional expectation $E(r(X)s(Y)|X)$ could take different values for different $X=x$, just as $X^{2}$ takes different values for different $X=x$, although the associated probability function would be the same.

So if I can show that the left- and right-hand sides take the same values for $X=x$, then since they both are associated with the same probability distribution for $X$, it will have shown that they are the same random variable.  So to do this, I pick any particular $X=x$ and for this we get

$$\mathbb{E}(r(X=x)s(Y)|X=x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}r(x)s(y)P(Y|X=x)dy$$

$$=r(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s(y)P(Y|X=x)dy = r(x)E(Y|X=x)$$

and the right-hand side is just the value of the random variable $r(X)E(Y|X)$ for every such $x$.

Comment: This seems to try to circumvent the correct approach mentioned by @Stefan in a comment. The cost is that this "proof" only applies to *discrete* random variables X.

Comment: @Did, Well, his comment used a lot of things I don't understand. I've heard of sigma algebras but only from recreational study, and I have no idea how to use them.

Comment: As I said, the cost is that the answer (now accepted...) is awfully incomplete. If you intended to restrict the setting to discrete random variables X (and to densitable random variables Y, apparently), you should have said so in the question.

Comment: @Did, I'm not restricting, or maybe I am and I don't know it. I don't understand the subject. That's kind of the reason I had to ask a question. The answer I gave here was the best I could do, sorry if it's not adequate for you.

Comment: "I don't understand the subject." OK. And this is why you did not even pretend to follow @Stefan's hint? Beats me.

Comment: @Did, I explained already, I don't know how to follow his hint because I don't understand sigma algebras. I already apologized for attempting an answer. Not sure what you want from me.